# Angular 4: Activate route with empty route param yields error: 'You provided 'null' where a stream was expected...'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-routing

If I go to `/my/route/8000`

It works.

But if I try to go to `/my/route` with no route params, I get an error:

`You provided 'null' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

```
ngOnInit() {
  // the observable method
  this.route.paramMap
     .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.number = params.get('number');
        return params.get('number');
     })
     .subscribe((number) => { return; });
}
```

Routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
   path    : 'my',
   children: [{
      path      : '',
      pathMatch : 'full',
      redirectTo: 'route'
   },  {
      path     : 'route',
      component: SubscriberRegisterComponent, 
   }, {
      path     : 'route/:number', // gets the route parameters
      component: SubscriberRegisterComponent,
   }]
}];
```

How come I can't visit my route directly without the route params?

If I comment the above observable method out and use `the no-observable method` then I can visit my route with empty params

```
  this.number = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('number ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.switchMap()` takes a function that should return an Observable.  Instead, you're returning the param value:

```
  this.route.paramMap
     .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.number = params.get('number');
        return params.get('number');
     })
```

You're also using the `switchMap` to do work (to set a class property) but Observables are designed for the work to be done in the subscribe method (or the `.do()` operators).  Do this instead:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe( (params:ParamMap) => {
    this.number = +params.get('number');
 });
```

As a sidenote, if your route sometimes takes a parameter and sometimes not, you don't need to define it twice! Optional parameters are not meant to be included in the route definition. Just keep:

```
{
  path     : 'route',
  component: SubscriberRegisterComponent, 
}
```

And learn how to use optional parameters. They will still be available to `paramMap`. [See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I'll remember to use `.do()` and `.subscribe()` from now on for doing work.